# DB scripts automation from GIT to AWS SQL server using Jenkins?

Tags: sql-server, git, amazon-web-services, jenkins

Hi Is there any one who can help me out with this....

I was trying to automate some DB scripts migration using Jenkins. All I am doing is Using a Jenkins job trying to migrate DB scripts which are in GIT repository to AWS server (SQL server 2008-R2) and execute those scripts...

What all the server and access credentials I need to have from DB server end(like access key, secret key, DNS name..etc) in order to configure a Jenkins job.

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean by "DB scripts". Are you trying to execute SQL code against an SQL Server DB, or perform automation using the AWS API? Is this DB on an EC2 instance or an RDS instance? Could you post an example from your script?

Answer (score 0):

## SQL access to the DB

For SQL access to the DB you need the following:

- Hostname or RDS endpoint
- TCP port number
- DB name
- DB user
- DB password

The Jenkins machine needs network access to the DB host, which means you need to allow this in the Security Groups and have VPC connectivity.

## AWS API access

For API access to AWS, the best practice is to have an IAM role assigned to the Jenkins machine. The role should have necessary permissions in the IAM policies attached to it.

In addition, you need to have internet access from the Jenkins machine or configure VPC endpoints so that Jenkins can reach the AWS API.

**NOTE:** You can't assign an IAM role to an existing EC2 machine. IAM roles can only be assigned during instance creation.